# Append link after another link

Tags: jquery

How can I append a link with jQuery after a link that has specific text in it? For example after "append after me".

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="#" class="myLink">some link</a>
    <a href="#" class="myLink">append after me</a>
    <a href="#" class="myLink">another link</a>
</div>


$(".links a").contains("append after me").append("<a href="">new link</a>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`:contains()` filter](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) instead of [`.contains()` method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/). Also to add a link *after* the link, use `.after()` instead of `.append()` (which appends to innerHTML).

```
$(".links a:contains('append after me')").after("<a href=''>new link</a>");
```

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same answer, so ill donate you my fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/426Ma/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different types of quotes so that it doesn't prematurely terminate your appended string.

```
$(".links a").contains("append after me").append("<a href=''>new link</a>");
```

Refer to Ketola's answer for a better explanation on ":contains".

Comment: `.contains()` is used for checking if a DOM element contains another element - not for checking HTML content.

Comment: also this would insert an anchor element inside an anchor element (linkception) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$( ".links a:contains('append after me')" ).after("<a href=''>new link</a>")
```

or this to put it at the end of the div

```
$( ".links a:contains('append after me')" ).next().after("<a href=''>new link</a>")
```