# How to append another directory link to <a> in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, subdirectory

I am looking to create a simple following link to append to the current location.

Straight to examples

www.domain.com/link/address

link required

www.domain.com/link/address/newbit

I have tried the following so far:

```
<a href=#/newdir> //fail
result: www.domain.com/link/address#/newdir

<a href=/newdir> //fail
result: www.domain.com/newdir

<a href=./newdir> // fail
result: www.domain.com/link/newdir
```

So unless I have to use the trailing forward slash on the previous link, it appears this is actually not that easy.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks

P.S. I would like to do this without jQuery or Javascript if possible

Comment: If you're already on `www.domain.com/link/address` you can use a relative URL, like `<a href="newdir/file.html">` to add to the current URL.

Comment: @adeneo wouldn't that overwrite the last part 'address' with 'newdir/file.html'?

Comment: It would, and it should, as without the last slash it's really not a directory

Comment: @adeneo I like the lazy approach to being able to view a page without the forward slash. Its easier for typing so I can test the page faster. I suppose that I may have to force the forward slash and just link all pages with forward slashes

Comment: Or you could do what every other sain person does, generate absolute URL's on the serverside ?

Comment: @adeneo thanks for that idea. It might save a bit of work however I was hoping to be able to do it with a native function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't be possible if you do not prepend your base path with JavaScript or when the links are rendered server-side.

Prefixing the links with a `/` means look from the root, which is "http://www.domain.com".

**EDIT** : Check the [base element on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). It will add a base path for *all* relatives URLs in the document.

**EDIT 2** : If you are already on /adress/, @Adeneo's suggestion will obviously work.

Comment: that could be quite useful knowing that for any root issues. just have to escape it if I use it in PHP then.

Comment: it could be useful, I am not sure how this would affect the system I am using though. I am mostly being lazy on the forward slash front as I am using an SEO replace for variables on a php script. I know its possible to add forward slashes whatever but would like to keep away from this. I have taken a look at the W3Schools link, thanks for reminding me about that element. I am not sure it would help even by dynamically creating it due to other file links being called by my PHP page.

Comment: as per comment, edit 2 will only work if page is set with a / on the end

Answer (score 1):

append using jquery here is a sample code...

```
<a href="" id="url">url</a>
$(function(){

var current_location='www.domain.com/link/address';

$("#url").attr('href',current_location+"/newbit");

});
```

Comment: quite simple, although using jquery. I may use this or create absolute links as per comment further up. I'll keep this question open a little bit longer although there does not appear to be a fixed simple answer as I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

If `www.domain.com/link/address` is the page that you are already on, then

```
<a href="newdir">newdir</a>
```

would be enough, resulting in `www.domain.com/link/address/newdir` address.

If not, you should use JS.

Comment: doesn't work without the forward slash already being in place

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in a clever way , you just have to add a jQuery function that gets the href value and redirect where you want after processing. like this

```
$("a").click( function () {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    // the variabel href is everything inside the attribut href
    location.href = "http://domain/" + href ;
});
```

Comment: on this particular method I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414509/append-link-after-another-link